# How to return a value without `return`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I return without `return` like devise's `authenticate!` method does?

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    authenticate! # After here, the code below will not be excuted.
    @group = Group.create(group_params)
    redirect_to groups_path
  end
end
```

I am wondering how to do this.

Comment: Why can't you return?

Comment: What do you mean, "code below is not executed"?

Comment: it isn't that it is returning, it is more along the fact that it isn't returning to your create function, and is redirecting. But still unclear on what exactly you are asking/want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devise `authenticate!` doesn't return on failure, it actually throw exceptions if the user isn't authenticated. The exception will get propagated all through the call chain, until it hits a matched `rescue` statement. The Rails framework is smart enough that it will rescue this kind of exception and convert specific exceptions to the corresponding HTTP status code, for example, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will be converted to `404`.

This is common programming tricks to *return* from deep call hierarchy.

```
def a
  raise "ha"
end
def b
  puts "calling a"
  a
  not executed
end
def c
  b rescue nil
end

c #=> calling a
```

And ruby provides `catch/throw` which serve for this kind of deeper jump.

```
catch(:ret) do
  (1..5).each do |i|
    (1..5).each do |j|
      puts i * j
      throw :ret if i * j > 3
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to return without using the keyword 'return'?

Ruby will automatically return the result from the last line in the method, if thats what you mean. but it would be the same as using the keyword 'return'.

Comment: I doubt that's what he's asking